# XML Relative Layout

Tags: android-layout

I have a question regarding Relative Layout. So I have this label called "bill" and I am trying ot create another label called "bill2" below it. I don't just want to put "bill2" label directly below it by calling Android:layout_below = " ". I want that second label, let's say, 50

Answer (score 1):

I advice that you read through the developer.android.com to understand relative layouts. That said, Android Relative layout, can get a bit confusing for people starting off, a quick basic walk through may help you understand it better.

Where to place the widget "within" the parent ? In other words, align the widget to which wall of the parent.

- `layout_alignParentRight` - Will stick the widget to the
  inner right wall of the parent
- `layout_alignParentLeft` -
  Will stick the widget to the innerleft wall of the parent
- `layout_alignParentTop` - Will stick the widget to the
  inner top wall of the parent
- `layout_alignParentBottom` -
  Will stick the widget to the inner bottom wall of the parent

Where to place this widget in relation to "another" widget (already defined). Specifying one of the below parameters will place the widget outside (obviously since the widget is not the parent) the relative widget

- `layout_bottom` - Will stick the widget top wall, to the outer bottom wall of the relative
- `layout_top` - Will stick the widget bottom wall, to the outer top wall of the relative
- `layout_toRight`  - Will stick the widget left wall, to the outer right wall of the relative
- `layout_toLeft` - Will stick the widget right wall, to the outer left wall of the relative

Where to place this widget in relation to "another" widget (already defined). Specifying one of the below parameters will place the widget outside (obviously since the widget is not the parent) the relative. These parameters are a bit different as compared to the ones explained above. This tells the widget to align with a wall of the relative, not stick to it.  Now, this parameter should be used in conjunction with other parameters for sake of clarity in code. As you read thru you will understand why.

- `layout_alignBottom` - Will stick (or may not) the widget left / right wall, to the right / left wall of the relative, and align the bottom walls of both widgets. Kinda like keeping 2 objects on a dining table. Both share the same bottom alignment.
- `layout_alignTop` - Will stick (or may not) the widget left / right wall, to the right / left wall of the relative, and align the top walls of both widgets. Kinda like keeping 2 objects suspended from the roof with ropes of same length. Both share the same top alignment.
- `layout_alignRight`  - Will stick (or may not) the widget top / bottom wall, to the bottom / top wall of the relative, and align the right walls of both widgets. Kinda like keeping 2 objects one above another stuck to the same wall. Both share the same right alignment.
- `layout_alignLeft` - Will stick (or may not) the widget top / bottom wall, to the bottom / top wall of the relative, and align the left walls of both widgets. Kinda like keeping 2 objects one above another stuck to the same wall. Both share the same left alignment.

Special Alignments - Where to place the widget within the parent. To center is horizontally, vertical or bang on center (both vertical and horizontal).

- `layout_centerHorizontal`
- `layout_centerVertical`
- `layout_centerInParent`

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to set the bill2 directly below the bill1 then just set the topMargin of the bill2. So it will put some space between the bill1 and bill2.

Hope you got the Point.